# What am I missing? I want to store my session to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mysql-workbench, express-session

I have my database up and running. The connection is working. I want to store my session in to the database.

Here's my code. When I run the server on my browser I get this error:
RequestError: No connection is specified for that request.

I just kept it simple in one app.js file.

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var session = require('express-session');
var MsSQLStore = require('mssql-session-store')(session);

var port = 3000;
var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection ({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '.....',
    database: 'node'
});

var sess = {
    secret: 'Pearl',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MsSQLStore(options)
};

var options = {
    connection: connection,
    ttl: 3600,
    reapInterval: 3600,
    reapCallback: function() {console.log('expired sessions were removed');}
};



if(app.get('env') === 'production') {
    app.set('trust proxy', 1)
    sess.cookie.secure = true
}

app.use(session(sess));



connection.connect();
connection.query('Select 1 + 1 AS solution', (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (err) throw err

    console.log('the solution is: ', rows[0].solution)
});

app.listen(port, (req, res) => {
    console.log('the server is running, ' + ' please, open your browser at http://localhost:%s', port);

});


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.end('Hello World');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In `store: new MsSQLStore(options)`, you are attempting to use `options` before you've assigned it a value so it will be `undefined` when you try to use it.  Move the definition and assignment of `options` to BEFORE you use it.

So, change this:

```
var sess = {
    secret: 'Pearl',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MsSQLStore(options)
};

var options = {
    connection: connection,
    ttl: 3600,
    reapInterval: 3600,
    reapCallback: function() {console.log('expired sessions were removed');}
};
```

to this:

```
const options = {
    connection: connection,
    ttl: 3600,
    reapInterval: 3600,
    reapCallback: function() {console.log('expired sessions were removed');}
};

const sess = {
    secret: 'Pearl',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MsSQLStore(options)
};
```

Incidentially, if you use `let` or `const` for these, then this would have been flagged by the interpreter as an error which is yet another reason to stop using `var` entirely.

Comment: thanks for replying. but that that dont fix it.. same error pops up.. i made the change as you pointed to.

Comment: @Bobby - It could also be that `connection.connect();` is AFTER you're trying to use the connection for your session initialization.

Comment: Hey thx for replying back. I dont think thats it because I moved that up before the session initialization. maybe it has something to do with the get route ?? im wondering..

Comment: @Bobby - So, these things are clearly wrong and needed to be fixed.  Just because it still doesn't work just means there are more issues before it starts working.  What is the stack trace that goes with the error: `RequestError: No connection is specified for that request.`?  What line of code and call stack does that happen with?  What GET request is in process when that happens?  If you temporarily comment out `app.use(session(sess));` does the error disappear?

Comment: thx for replying back. yes so i commented that out and they error disappeared. here's the only other thing that appears. at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11).

Comment: @Bobby - Ok, that confirms the error apparently comes from the `mssql-session-store` module.  In look at [your DB doc](https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/), it's pretty clear this is a problem with your database connection.  Things to look into: 1) The `connection.connect()` call is not working, 2) something else is closing the database, 3) The right session table doesn't exist in your database,   If it were me, I'd look into the `mssql-session-store` code and find where this error was coming from and perhaps set a breakpoint on it so I could step through it and see what is occurring.

Comment: FYI, that stack trace means that the error occurs inside a callback passed to `process.nextTick()` which might help you find where it is occurring in the `mssql-session-store` source code.